# Pytorch Exception in Thread: ValueError: signal number 32 out of range

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in Thread: ValueError: signal number 32 out of range
```

The specific tutorial that raises an issue for me is the training a classifier (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html), the specific line is:

```
dataiter = iter(trainloader)
```

and the full error traceback is:

```
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/chenchen/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/home/chenchen/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/home/chenchen/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 139, in _serve
signal.pthread_sigmask(signal.SIG_BLOCK, range(1, signal.NSIG))
File "/home/chenchen/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/signal.py", line 60, in pthread_sigmask
sigs_set = _signal.pthread_sigmask(how, mask)
ValueError: signal number 32 out of range
```

My operation system is Ubuntu 18.10 and my python env is Anaconda3 for python 3.6. I installed pytorch from the latest source. My cuda version is 10.0.

Comment: Please post some code, reducing it to a minimal, complete and verifiable example, otherwise it's really difficult to help you out...

Comment: There is a recent issue on this for python from april this year. You can check it out here:
https://bugs.python.org/issue33329
If your python install is older than that you might try doing a new install to get the fix (resp. update or create a new conda environment). Maybe this solves your problem.

Answer (score 12):

I have faced a similar issue and it got resolved when I set:

```
num_workers=0
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like this was a bug in Python (https://bugs.python.org/issue33329).

For Python **3.6**, it got fixed in 3.6.6, released around July 2019 (see the [release notes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-6-6-release-candidate-1) mentioning it). (You can check which version you have by running `python3 --version`.)

For Python **3.5**, you'd want at least 3.5.7 (... [release notes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-5-7-final)).

Meanwhile... I haven't tried this personally, but Ubuntu 18.10 [seems to have Python 3.6.7 available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/python/python3.6), so a simple `sudo apt install python3.6` might solve this?

Comment: As of July 2022, upgrading python from 3.6.5 to 3.6.6 as suggested above solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the python version from 3.5 to 3.6.1 by using `pip install python==3.6.1` and that resolved the problem.